# How to insert an auto-generated ID of one table into another table's ID

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am trying to make a project which is an Online shopping website. I have three tables,namely, Category Table, Sub-Category Table and Products table. In category table I have `CategoryID` and `CategoryName` as the two fileds.In Sub-Category table I have `CategoryID`, `Sub-CategoryID` and `SubCategoryName` as the fields, and in products table I have `CategoryID`, `SubCategoryID` , `ProductID` and `ProductName`.

Now in category table , the categoryID is autogenerated and set as primary key.In sub-Category table, the none of the keys are auto generated and both the categoryID and subCategory ID are set to combined primary keys. Now ,when I insert a categoryName into the category table, I want the CategoryID(auto-generated) to be inserted in the categoryID column of the SubCategory table and the CategoryID column of the ProductTable. There is a lot of content in the net on this matter, but none solves exactly my problem.

Comment: So you just want a new row created in the target tables? Or is this in the context of a stored procedure and you need to find out what row was just created and use that value moving forward?

Comment: So you want to auto-insert the sub-category with the same name and the fk referencing the newly created category? Why do you need to insert something in the `Product` table when a new category was created?

Comment: @Brian, Can you elaborate  the stored procedure method. I want exactly that to happen. I want the CategoryID(which is auto incremented) to be inserted into the other two tables as soon as a row in inserted in Category table

Comment: I am not sure why you would really want to do that.  You would be better off with a foreign key constraint on the other tables and manually inserting the values into the table.  Check out stored procedures and @@identity.

Comment: No I don't want to insert data manually into the database. I want to have an AdminControl panel, from where he can insert CategoryName,SubCategoryName and also ProductName

Comment: @TimSchmelter I want the CategoryID to be copied into the other tables ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think You shud user SCOPE_IDENTITY for that

SCOPE_IDENTITY returns the last identity value generated for any table.

Answer (score 0):

I feel there is a bad smell in your design.

You do not need to have a composite primary key in your sub tables since you already have a unique identifier defined in your table. Instead, just use one column as a primary key and add foreign key relations to your sub tables.

Comment: What is the use of foreign keys in this context? If I use that can I insert values directly in sub-Category and ProductTable

Comment: The use of foreign keys is to ensure referential integrity of your data. If, for example, you can't 1) Have a Sub-Category without a related Category 2) Have a Product without a related Sub-Category, Then you should set up CategoryID in the Sub-Category table as a foreign key to CategoryID in the Category table and set up Sub-CategoryID in the Products table as foreign key to Sub-CategoryID in the Sub-Category table. Also, you should practice normalization in that CategoryID is not needed in the Products table at all.

Comment: @Kevin ... can you provide some links or tutorials on this

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO Category (....) VALUES(....)

DECLARE @id int;
SELECT @id=SCOPE_IDENTITY();

INSERT INTO Subcategory(CatagoryID,....) VALUES(@id,....)
INSERT INTO Product (CategoryID,....) Values(@id,...)
```